# Is there any method for detecting yaml issue for AWS deployment by kubectl?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I think that there are lots of DevOps engineer realized this issue. Because I am from a software background. Explanations for syntax not enough for me. Below YAML is working for the Azure environment but not working for EKS and AWS.

Error:

```
 error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec): unknown field "spec" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

My deployment yaml :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name:  my-flask
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-flask
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-flask
  spec:
   containers:
     - name: my-flask
       image: yusufkaratoprak/awsflaskeks:latest
       ports:
         - containerPort: 5000
```

[image]

Comment: the pod `spec` (the second one) needs to be indented right to be under `template`. also, it shouldn't work on either aws or azure from my understanding.

Comment: regarding the validation part, there is nothing built-in with `kubectl` IIRC (there is a `--dry-run` flag in `kubectl` to see the result without actually applying the objects but that isn't a validator per se) and you can have a look at third party tools like [`yamllint`](https://github.com/adrienverge/yamllint), [`kubeval`](https://www.kubeval.com/), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is some indentation problem with your yamls.
the field second`spec` is under the template.
will also encourage you to see the official docs of [kubernetes_deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name:  my-flask
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-flask
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-flask
    spec:
    containers:
        - name: my-flask
          image: yusufkaratoprak/awsflaskeks:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
```

Comment: hi ;   I rewrote my deployment .yaml like yours. but error occurs again : "
error: unable to recognize "deployment.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version ""

Comment: @Penguen try again...
miss the apiversion in markdown syntax